# Open Layers 3 Zoom map event handler

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need to handle a zoom event in Open Layers 3.

The following is my code:

```
map_object = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
controls: controls_list,
interactions: interactions_list,
overlays: [overlay],
layers: [OSM_raster, WFS_layer],
    view: view
});


map_object.on("Zoom", function() {
  console.log('Zooming...');
});
```

This code runs with no errors and shows a map, but there is no output to the console, suggesting this function isn't firing.

I have also tried:

```
map_object.on("drag", function() {
  console.log('Dragging...');
});
```

And this too does nothing.

Any help as to how to handle map control events in OL3 would be much appreciated (particularly zooming!).  Note I have tried 'zoom' as well as 'Zoom' for the type field of the on method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try with `moveend` event. (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapEvent-MapEvent.html#event:moveend).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue of handling a zoom event.  I need to know when and only when zoom is occurring (not pan or rotate too) and which way the zoom is going.  I have however found a workaround solution which I will post shortly which doesn't involve 'non-stable' events and works perfectly.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: would `map.getView().on('change:resolution')` fit your needs?

Comment: It works but is the `change:resolution` event the minimal way ? Can anyone confirm this ?

Answer (score 18):

Just to add to this, you can check variations of events available with 'propertychange', from what I am seeing, there is no explicit `.on ('zoom', ...)` but rather you can access 'resolution' and other properties as mentioned in previous comments:

```
map.getView().on('propertychange', function(e) {
   switch (e.key) {
      case 'resolution':
        console.log(e.oldValue);
        break;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734512/open-layers-3-zoom-map-event-handler#comment42132882_26777184) by [tonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29655/tonio), the way to listen on zoom change, which is called *resolution change* in openlayers terminology, is with

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

I find this is better (more succinct, less cruft) than listening on the general `propertychange` and verifying manually if the change concerns resolution.

This fires rapidly when using the mouse button so throttling it might be a good idea before launching any computation that waits for it to change.

[Documentation for View](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the moveend event...

> We will need a global variable to alocate map’s view zoom level. I’ve
>   named it as currentZoomLevel.
>
> There is available a moveend event. Let’s use it, and add a zoom level
>   check function..
>
> In case of there’s a new zoom level, we trigger a zoomend event to
>   DOM’s document.
>
> Finally we will need to add zoomend listener to the document element.
>
> ```
> var = currentZoomLevel;
>
> map.on('moveend', checknewzoom);
>
> function checknewzoom(evt)
> {
>    var newZoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom();
>    if (newZoomLevel != currentZoomLevel)
>    {
>       currentZoomLevel = newZoomLevel;
>       $(document).trigger("zoomend", zoomend_event);
>    }
> }
>
> $(document).on('zoomend', function () {
>    console.log("Zoom");
>    //Your code here
> });
> ```

[Source](http://jongarrido.es/blog/2015/09/30/zoomend-event-in-openlayers-3/)

Comment: replace *zoomend_event* with *evt* and pass it to zoomend event function to use in own code